# Update statement with select to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

```
SELECT rollID 
FROM [dbo].[dbo_Roll] a
  INNER JOIN [evt_Building Permits] b
    ON LEFT(a.rollnumber, LEN(a.rollnumber)-4) = b.rollnumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

And I want to update the result to this table `[evt_Building Permits].roll_id = [dbo].[dbo_Roll].rollID`?

How can I attain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE b
SET b.roll_id = a.rollID
FROM 
    [dbo].[dbo_Roll] a
  INNER JOIN 
    [evt_Building Permits] b
  ON LEFT(a.rollnumber, LEN(a.rollnumber)-4) = b.rollnumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
update b
set rollID = a.rollID
from [dbo].[dbo_Roll] a
inner join [evt_Building Permits] b
on LEFT(a.rollnumber, LEN(a.rollnumber)-4) = b.rollnumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
update b
set b.roll_id = a.rollID
from [dbo].[dbo_Roll] a
inner join [evt_Building Permits] b
on LEFT(a.rollnumber, LEN(a.rollnumber)-4) = b.rollnumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```